# Slutsky's theorem with convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider two sequences of real-valued random variables $\{X_n\}_n$ $\{Y_n\}_n$ and a sequence of real numbers $\{B_n\}_n$. Suppose we have that

$$
\frac{X_n}{B_n}-\frac{Y_n}{B}\rightarrow_p0
$$

and

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} B_n=B
$$

I think we can conclude that $\frac{X_n}{B}-\frac{Y_n}{B}\rightarrow_p 0$. But, which rule am I actually using? Slutsky's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the claim is, in general, not correct as the following counterexample shows:

Set$$X_n := n+1 \qquad Y_n := n \qquad B_n := \frac{n+1}{n}$$ then

- $B_n \to B := 1$ as $n \to \infty$
- $\frac{X_n}{B_n} - \frac{Y_n}{B} = n-n=0$; hence in particular $\frac{X_n}{B_n}-\frac{Y_n}{B} \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\to} 0$.
- $\frac{X_n}{B}-\frac{Y_n}{B} = (n+1)-n = 1$ does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (neither pointwise nor in probability).